# Commutativity of the square root of matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ two positive definite matrices such that $AB = BA$, that is $A$ commutes with $B$. It is easy to prove that $A^{1/2}$ commutes with $A$, indeed $AA^{1/2} = A^{3/2}=A^{1/2}A$, but I am wondering whether it is true that $A^{1/2}B = BA^{1/2}$, in other words that $AB = BA$ implies $A^{1/2}B = BA^{1/2}$. The best clue I have - and it isn't much - is that I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P$ be a polynomial such that $P(\lambda) = \sqrt{\lambda}$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.  Then $A^{1/2} = P(A)$.  A polynomial in $A$ commutes with every matrix that commutes with $A$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you suggest a reference for the proof of this fact (a polynomial in A commutes with any matrix that commutes with A)? I had never come across this result before.

Comment: It's obvious.  If $A$ commutes with $B$, then so does $A^n$ for all positive integers $n$, and then so does any linear combination of these.

Comment: @RobertIsrael In what sense is the square root a linear combination of these?

Comment: a polynomial is a linear combination of $A^n$ terms